# Function doesn't trigger after Yes/No alert prompt selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-drive-api, alert

Working in a sheet with Google Apps Scripts.

When the page loads (onOpen), I have a YES_NO alert box display. When the user clicks YES, the conditional IF statement works up to, but not including any DriveApp calls - in this case, "makeCopy". I'm assuming this is a security measure built in as DriveApp is a Google API function, but not sure.

In script view/debug mode, the 3 variables populate and the makeCopy function works. But as an end user, everything happens, but nothing happens and no visible error at makeCopy.

When I isolate the makeCopy code as it's own function and call it from a button as an end user, this works without issue (just the one-time authorization prompt as I expect).

```
//other stuff happens up to this point
var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Name of Alert", "Hello! If you click yes, this will move your file to another folder.",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);

if (result === SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.YES) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxx-hard-coded-here");
  var fileName = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId())
 DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(fileName,destFolder);

  } 

} else {
  Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');  //nothing happens, alert box is closed
}

//closing brackets ends the function here
```

- debugging variables
- isolated the line of code to its own function to try as an end user and in debug mode
- tried changing the alert type from YES_NO to OK to

Answer (score -1):

I have tested your code and it seems to be working just fine. I noticed that a part of the code is missing when declaring the "fileName" variable, but I assumed this was just a problem with the copy/paste you made when creating the post. To be sure that this is not the root of the issue I will include the full code that you need below:

```
function myFunction(e){
 //other stuff happens up to this point
 var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Name of Alert", "Hello! If you click 
 yes, this will move your file to another 
 folder.",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);

 if (result === SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.YES) {

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxx-hard-coded-here");
   var fileName = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).getName();
   DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(fileName,destFolder); 

  } else {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');  
   //nothing happens, alert box is closed
  }
 //closing brackets ends the function here
}
```

The other things I set up on my end to make the script works are:

1. Set an onOpen trigger in the triggers section of the script and select your function.[setting trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I2XY.png)
2. Check the sharing settings of the spreadsheet, and ensure that people that will use it have **edit** access to the file.

Comment: If you will use an on open installable trigger, you should change the name of the onOpen function as it is a reserved name used for a simple trigger. Failing on doing this the fuction will be triggered twice when the spreadsheet is opened.

Comment: Hi @Rubén, Thank you for the insight.  I have updated my answer to avoid triggering the function twice. Would you consider my answer now an adequate solution to the question?

Comment: Thanks, @MatiasCG and Rubén - the file is copied to the folder as expected. It's successful with the .getName() added and onOpen trigger added, but per comment from Rubén, I will rename the onOpen to avoid double calls.